# Is there a downside to frequently changing jobs?

Tags: dragon-quest-9

I'd like to change my Mage to an Armamentalist to build up abilities, and then come back to Mage later.

Is there a limit to the number of times I can switch jobs in this fashion?  Is there a downside to doing this?

I've read that there is something called "revocation" which has a limit.  Is that something different?  (I'm not yet in the end-game.)

Comment: Don't know how well it helps your circumstances, but just gonna toss this [related question about the frequency of job changes](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6372/when-to-change-occupations-in-dragon-quest-ix) at you. ♪

Comment: Gotcha, I took a look at that one.  I'm wondering if this revocation is the same thing as changing jobs, and if there's a limit on the amount of times I can do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no downside.  In fact, its a very handy way of getting some early skill points by switching jobs and leveling up very fast by hunting metal slimes, metal medleys, lmses, etc.  (When you switch jobs you keep all unspent sklil points)

As for revocation, it is completely different, once you beat the game, you can revocate a character once it is at level 99 in a class.  It resets that character to level 1 in that class, but you keep the skill points you have earned.  Revocating is the only way to max out all your skills since reaching level 99 in all classes does not give you enough skill points to do so.

Revocating also has another benefit: it improves the chances of getting a higher quality treasure map when you complete a dungeon.

Comment: While you're answering this one, you might want to also toss some words [over here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8317/whats-revocation), which has some further inquiries about the effects and availability of revocation.